# Switch to the home (to the launcher)

Tags: android

Now my problem :
I wrote a function to put an application in the foreground, it works fine for every applications, except for one: the launcher (com.android.launcher).

The function :

```
public void switchTo(String activityName)
{
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);       
    try
    {   
        //Specials cases (Contacts and launcher app)
        if(activityName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.contacts"))
        {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts","com.android.contacts.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity" ));
        }
        else
        {
            intent=this.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(activityName);
        }

        if(null != intent)
        {
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            this.activity.startActivity(intent);
            this.activity.finish();
        }

    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When "activityName" is equal to "com.android.launcher", nothing happens, not even an exception, but the function is called (I verified with a "Log" function).

So do you have any idea of where the mistake is?

Answer (score 5):

I finally find an answer to my question, i just have to add a case if the process name is "com.android.launcher" and put in this case :

`intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);`

Thanks for reading my problem and i hope this can help some people here !